# Hedging Strategies involving Forwards and Options

Tags: options, futures, hedging

"An investor or business with long exposure to an asset can hedge exposure by either entering into a short futures contract or by buying a put option. An investor or business with a short exposure to an asset can hedge exposure by either entering into a long futures contract or by buying a call option."

Can anyone please explain the meaning of long exposure and short exposure?

Comment: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/net-exposure.asp,  https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/netlong.asp, https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/netshort.asp

Comment: Long exposure to gold: you profit when the price of gold goes up (example: you own a gold mine in South America), short exposure to gold: you profit when the price of gold goes down (example: you promised your boyfriend a gold ring but you have not purchased it yet).

Comment: @Alex C Thank you!